# Jquery calendar with marked dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Im looking for a calendar component for jquery that looks like the one in outlook navigation pane. A smaller calendar where you can easily mark dates as bold if there is an event planned for this date. Anyone have any suggestions?

I guess you could take any kind of date picker and modify it but I would like something that just works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are looking for this one:

http://marcgrabanski.com/pages/code/jquery-ui-datepicker